# Navigation controller doesnt add back button

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view which pushes a new view onto the screen.

When the new view is shown, there is no back button in the navigation controller.

I have the following in one view

[image]

and I push a new view using the following code

```
[photoViewController setAsset:[assets objectAtIndex:(cell.rowNumber * 4) + index]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:photoViewController animated:YES];
[photoViewController release];
```

When the view appears the following is visible

[image]

How do I add the back button and where would I add the same share button to the bar in the second view?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set a title in your first view. The back button uses the title of the previous view. If one is not set then the back button will not be displayed.

In the viewDidLoad method of your first view, use self.title = @"title";

Comment: Great. After pressing the back button I get a crash report. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array' Does pushing a view dealloc the first view?

Comment: Pushing a view onto a navigation controller does not send a release message to the underlying view.  I would recommend this: add a symbolic breakpoint with the "symbol" set to objc_exception_throw [as shown in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQn5jU_RHJs). Then, when that crash happens you can look in your stack trace and see where in your code you are trying to access index 1 of an empty array.

Comment: @Helium3 Pushing a new view does not release the view underneath it, but it's possible during a memory warning the underneath view will get sent a memory warning, which WILL cause the view itself (not the view controller) to be sent `release`. It will then execute `-viewDidUnload`. So, if you're futsing around with your array in viewDidUnload or in the memory warning code, that might be what's happening.

Comment: @jbrennan: I dont, that is what is so weird. The array is empty when returning to the view? No memory warnings, no viewDidUnload call.

Comment: @Simon Goldeen: I know where I am calling it. It is when I select a thumbnail for the second time(when the navigation controller returns to the view. Im not sure what the issue is though. I dont release the array or set it to nil.

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that there is no back button displayed in the navigation bar for the pushed controller, because it is standard, out-of-the-box, behavior to give you one for free. Your photoViewController hasn't overridden `-(UINavigationItem*)navigationItem;`, has it?

As for adding the "Share" button to the second controller, you can just set it through the controller's navigationItem property when the its view loads:

```
// In the .m file of whatever class photoViewController is...  
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIBarButtonItem* rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];
    [rightBarButtonItem release];
}
```

You can use the same approach to set a custom back button, just get yourself another UIBarButtonItem and set it as the leftBarButtonItem of your UINavigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the NSZombieEnable in your enviornment variable in your projects executable ,this will help you to debug.Well this crash genrally occurs ,because array contains elements less then the count you are specifying.you need to work with your this code, i think so....

```
[photoViewController setAsset:[assets objectAtIndex:(cell.rowNumber * 4) + index]];
```

and also put the breakpoints in your table view method didselect row at index path,cell for row at index path and number of rows and hopefully you would be able to figure out

Answer (score 0):

U should not set backButton on VIewDidLoad, instead u code it on DidSelect

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIBarButtonItem *btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
btn.title=@"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=btn;
[btn release];

  }
```